# Oracle APEX form based on multiple tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Can I create a form in APEX which creates/updates records in multiple tables? For example two tables with a one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Automated Row Fetch` mechanism, you can use two different ARF for two tables. If you want to have more control, you can define your `INSERT/UPDATE` statements yourself usign `Page Processes`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create a view that returns the joined tables and base the Apex form on that.  You may need to add INSTEAD OF triggers to the view to be able to insert and update successfully.

Comment: Please, may you say what you mean ? take into consideration that i'm not good in SQL please.

Comment: I tried to have more than one process "ARP" but it doesn't work, and no place has answer for that question, one form has more than one ARP that insert data into more than one table